# How can I pass JVM options to SBT to use when running the app or test cases?

Tags: scala, jvm, sbt

I would like to specify JVM options when running my app or the tests for the app through SBT. Specifically, I need to be able to give the JVM the -Djava.security.policy parameter so that my policy is loaded and used for the test.

How can I do this with SBT?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With [xsbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt), you could run your test in a [forked JVM](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Forking) (because of one of the reasons mentioned in "[Running Project Code](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Running-Project-Code)".

If you are using a forked jvm:

> specify the configuration to affect only the main or test run tasks:

```
scala javaOptions in (Test,run) += "-Xmx8G"
```

You should be able to specify any other options to that JVM through `javaOptions`.

---

The [OP David Eagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902456/david-eagen) reports that the following configuration didn't work at first, not because of the sbt options, but because of the path:

```
lazy val escacheServer = 
  Project( "escache-server", 
           file("server"), 
           settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(resolvers ++= 
                        Seq(scala_tools_snapshots, typesafe_repo), 
                        libraryDependencies ++= escacheServerDeps, 
                        javaOptions in run += "-Djava.security.policy=jini.policy", 
                        fork in run := true 
                      ) 
         ).dependsOn(escache) }
```

> It looks like my problem was that `jini.policy` wasn't found in the current directory.
>   I set the full path and now it runs.

Comment: Where do I set javaOptions? When I add it to the settings for the project this way it doesn't appear to do anything: 
  lazy val escacheServer = Project("escache-server", file("server"),
     settings = buildSettings ++ 
      Seq(resolvers ++= Seq(scala_tools_snapshots, typesafe_repo), 
          libraryDependencies ++= escacheServerDeps,
          javaOptions in run += "-Djava.security.policy=jini.policy",
          fork in run := true
          ) ).dependsOn(escache)
}

Comment: It looks like the JVM options do actually get set when I use that in my project. I tested it by setting the max heap to 24G which the system I am using can not handle. Sure enough SBT reported the     failure: [error] Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx=24G -Djava.security.policy=jini.policy    It looks like my problem was that jini.policy wasn't found in the current directory. I set the full path and now it runs... Thanks VonC.

Comment: @David: excellent, I have included your config and conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Hey all, my understanding (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/KBzk3i2sxQc) is that you cannot fork in Test.  Instead, you have to add any options required for tests to the sbt script itself.  This may be my misunderstanding of the group post above as the documentation seems to imply otherwise. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SplittingField: interesting. That should be mentioned in the xsbt mailing list for a more definitive answer though.