# How do I specify a config file with sbt 0.12.2 for sbt test?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, playframework-2.1

I have a Play! project with unit tests and I am trying to run tests on my staging environment using sbt. Before I upgraded to Play 2.1, when I was using Play 2.0.4 and sbt 0.11.3 I could do `$ sbt -Dconfig.file=conf/staging.conf test`. Now `sbt test` seems to use the default application.conf no matter what I specify for -Dconfig.file.

`sbt start -Dconfig.file=conf/staging.conf` still works fine. Is this behavior a bug with sbt 0.12.2 or should I be specifying a config file for running tests in a different way?

Comment: If you want to add java options to only `sbt test` and not other configurations then you can do
`javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"` 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121889/how-can-i-pass-jvm-options-to-sbt-to-use-when-running-the-app-or-test-cases)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

test is using forked jvm.
Use javaOptions sbt setting to pass jvm options to it e.g.

`javaOptions ++= Seq("-Dconfig.file=conf/staging.conf")`
or

`javaOptions ++= collection.JavaConversions.propertiesAsScalaMap(System.getProperties).map{ case (key,value) => "-D" + key + "=" +value }.toSeq`

Answer (score 11):

Similar approach is to just pass the config file to use, while triggering the sbt test

First, in the **Build.scala** file

```
val testOptions = "-Dconfig.file=conf/" + Option(System.getProperty("test.config")).getOrElse("application") + ".conf"

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
    javaOptions in Test += testOptions
)
```

Then, in the command line to run the test with **integ.conf**

```
sbt -Dtest.config=integ test
```

to use the default **application.conf**

```
sbt test
```