# How can I specify a different config file for testing in Play 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.1

I would like to define different database connections for multiple test environments(Production, Staging, Development). After reading the post "[How do I specify a config file with sbt 0.12.2 for sbt test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399161/how-do-i-specify-a-config-file-with-sbt-0-12-2-for-sbt-test)" it seems that it was possible in earlier versions of Play, by using the follwing SBT setting:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"
)
```

But if I use this setting in my Build.scala, I get the following error:

```
not found: value javaOptions
```

So my question is, how can I define different connections for different test environments?

---

**Edit:**
A possible workaround would be to override the default setting during testing. This can be done with a environment variable.

```
object Config {
  var defaultConfig = Map(
    "db.default.user" -> "user",
    "db.default.pass" -> "************"
  )

  def additionalConfiguration(): Map[String, _] = sys.env.getOrElse("PLAY_TEST_SCOPE", "") match {
    case "development" => {
      defaultConfig += "db.default.url" -> "jdbc:mysql://host:3306/development"
      defaultConfig
    }
    case "staging" => {
      defaultConfig += "db.default.url" -> "jdbc:mysql://host:3306/staging"
      defaultConfig
    }
    case "production" => {
      defaultConfig += "db.default.url" -> "jdbc:mysql://host:3306/production"
      defaultConfig
    }
    case _ => {
      throw new Exception("Environment variable `PLAY_TEST_SCOPE` isn't defined")
    }
  }
}
```

And then running a fake application with this configuration.

```
FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Config.additionalConfiguration())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`javaOptions` is contained within the [Keys object](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.Keys%24).

Make sure that you use the proper import in your `Build.scala` file:

```
import Keys._
```

Answer (score 8):

we can mix the above solutions, to pass the config file as a parameter to sbt.
This will be useful to integrate the test in CI pipeline

First, in the **Build.scala** file

```
val testOptions = "-Dconfig.file=conf/" + Option(System.getProperty("test.config")).getOrElse("application") + ".conf"

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
    javaOptions in Test += testOptions
)
```

Then, in the command line to run the test with **integ.conf**

```
sbt -Dtest.config=integ test
```

to use the default **application.conf**

```
sbt test
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful. I struggled few days to make it work with CI and your comment helped me alot.

Answer (score 5):

Update for Play 2.5.x

Explicit import for import Keys._ is no longer required, and the vm param for config resource location has changed.

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=<conf_name>.conf"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can run your application from console with alternative config file, anyway you need to use `-Dconfig.file` with full path as there are some problems ... that I can't realize with other option. For an example in unix env:

```
play -Dconfig.file=/home/akkie/play/some-project/conf/local_akkie_dev.conf "~run 9123"
```

Of course for easier launching you can create bash script for calling this line.

**Edit:** Note that you don't need to write whole config in each additional config file, as you can just ***include*** your main config at beginning and then overwrite only required properties :

```
include "application.conf"

key.to.override=blah
```

Take a look to the [official doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionConfiguration)

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I'm aware of this option, but this doesn't work for testing.

Comment: and what is there are the same settings for both dev and production modes? Copy-paste in dev config and prod config is not a good idea.

Comment: whayyyy, it can be included? it's magical. by the way, do you know how I can run the app in any custom mode I want, for example, "my_developer_mode"?

Comment: well, what if I need to run "sbt" (not play) with a different config file? sbt   -Dconfig.file=conf/application.prod.conf doesn't work.