# How to set custom configuration file for testing?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

Test (as executed using `activator test`) uses `conf/application.conf`. I'd like to set a custom configuration file just for testing. How?

There is a solution in [How do I specify a config file with sbt 0.12.2 for sbt test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15399161/1305344) but it uses `Build.scala` that's not available in play 2.3. I tried to put `javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/local.conf"` in `build.sbt` but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is indeed to use `javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/local.conf"` in `build.sbt`.

It didn't work when I was posting the question as I used `fork in Test := false` in `build.sbt` that disabled forking and hence `javaOptions in Test` had no effect on the test run setup.